# Side-effects when calling %TypedArray%.prototype.set on itself?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, language-lawyer

Item 24 in [Section 22.2.3.22.2 of the ECMAScript spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-%typedarray%.prototype.set-typedarray-offset) mentions that when the source and target buffers have the same value, which in code is when `a.set(a, 0);` is called where `a` is a TypedArray, an implementation should clone the source buffer (it mentions potential side-effects).

My question is **why is this cloning necessary and what is an example of code that would produce an observable side-effect if it wasn't?**

Comment: The *source* buffer is cloned, not the target.

Comment: Looks like it's a typo in the spec there, thanks.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it it doesn't really matter since they're the same when cloning has to happen :) I need more coffee.

Comment: I compared that line to version 8 of the spec and they indeed changed it to `srcBuffer`, so you're right! Don't know why it matters which I guess is part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

The spec text in question is this:

> b. Set srcBuffer to ? CloneArrayBuffer(srcBuffer, srcByteOffset, srcByteLength, %ArrayBuffer%).
> NOTE: %ArrayBuffer% is used to clone srcBuffer because is it known to not have any observable side-effects.

This note is saying that the `%ArrayBuffer%` constructor is used (instead of `this.constructor` or `this.constructor[@@species]`, as would be more typical), because it is known that calling `%ArrayBuffer%` will not have any side effects.